# How create an identical timestamp format as used in ppp.log file in a shell script?

Tags: macos, command-line, script, logs

In the need to add custom logging messages to ppp.log, I see that the date and time are missing when outputting the command to `>> /var/log/ppp.log`. Other pppd related messages in ppp.log are prepended with a timestamp format that is similar to: "`Sat Apr  9 17:18:02 2016 :` ". My goal is to output this exact date time format in a *Mavericks* shell script

I know that other log files have different date/time timestamps. I want to re-create the format as used in ppp.log.

#### Regression

This Mac OS X 10.9 environment is configured with a dutch language locale. Therefore `$ echo $(date '+%a')` returns "`za`" instead of the desired "`Sat`". That is the part that can be fixed by `export LC_TIME="C"` or `export LC_TIME="POSIX"`. I have tried to read the `date` and `pppd` man page. However then there is still the abbreviated alphabetic timezone name *CEST* (the `%Z` part in `$ date +%Z`) in the output "`Sat Apr  9 18:12:12 CEST 2016`".

I know I can create the format using all the different `$ date` format codes, like `%a %b %e` etcetera. Though I guess there is  a shorter way, isn't there?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching, a [search for "date format without alphabetic time zone abbreviation"](https://www.google.com/search?q=date%20format%20without%20alphabetic%20time%20zone%20abbreviation) returned [Info on ISO 8601, the date and time representation standard](https://www.cs.tut.fi/%7Ejkorpela/iso8601.html). That information helped me to find out that the timestamp format that is being used in Mavericks its /private/var/log/ppp.log file, is actually the ANSI C's asctime() format.

## C asctime

To create C style asctime in a shell, a non English system might need to override the environment variable for time messages:

```
export LC_TIME="C"
```

And then there is the `$ date` formatting option `%c` that now displays local date time in the desired format:

```
$ date +%c
Sat Apr  9 21:10:20 2016
```

---

<sup>A tip when using `echo date`, do put the date between apostrophes `echo "$(date +%c)"`, otherwise the filler space in single digit dates might be stripped from the output:</sup>

```
$ echo $(date +%c)
Sat Apr 9 21:13:57 2016
$ echo "$(date +%c)"
Sat Apr  9 21:14:30 2016
```